# Net.Sockets : PC Portnumber changes dynamically in LAN via (DLINK)router

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sockets

Hi i am creating server/client application using .net.Sockets something like cybercafe software.

Im following this example on codeproject  [Simple Socket Chat Program](http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_socket_programming.htm)

there is no problem i run it on local pc. But when i run the client in the other pc in network i got a problem.

says :

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I tried to use netstat -a on cmd and i found out that the portnumbers of all the p.c on our network always changes.

Is there any way to do it without using portnumber and just hostname or ipaddress only.

I need help...

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 0):

First, the random port numbers under `Local Address` in netstat are done so that everything gets a unique local port.

Also, a port is necessary for sockets.

The problem you are having is most likely because the firewall where your server software is located is blocking that port. For Windows 7 (and presumably Vista), you can unblock the port by running `WF.msc`, going to `Inbound Rules` on the left, clicking `New Rule` on the right, and adding a new program or port rule. The rest of the steps should be self-explanatory.